# What did I install (NPM)?

Tags: node.js, npm, package

I was trying to install forever with the package manager NPM.

I ran the following code:

```
sudo npm install foever -g
```

I misspelled "forever" obviously, but it did something. It said:

> - foever@0.0.1-security
>     updated 1 package in 0.163s

I can't find any info on foever. Does anyone have any idea what this did to my system?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/foever

Comment: Pretty much nothing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/foever

Comment: Check in your npm folder for the installation. On _windows_ it is in - `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\\npm` folder. You can uninstall it using `npm -un foever`.

Comment: Why do you use `sudo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you installed the [`foever`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/foever) package.

The original `foever` package was probably a malicious package used to [typosquat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting) the `forever` package. NPM recognized this, removed the malicious package, and placed an empty package there instead to prevent future (malicious) usage of this name.

Answer (score -1):

run

```
npm uninstall <module_name>
```

and you can get rid of it since its of no use.